# Stripping "extra spaces" in du -sk for bash script?

Tags: ssh, bash, scripting, shell

I am trying to use `du -sk` to get the size of two folders

```
dirsize_temp=`du -sk /folder/path/here`
```

and then an if statement to compare the sizes. The only issue is that when you run the command, it returns something like

```
123456         /folder/path/here
```

I am currently using

```
dirsize=${dirsize_temp%%/*}
```

to strip the "`/folder/path/here`" part, but I am having problems getting rid of the spaces. They do not seem to be *actual* spaces, so "`${dirsize//\ /}`" or "`${dirsize// /}`" does not work to remove them, but they still keep me from comparing two variables. Is there some escape character I am missing, or an easier way to get the size of two folders without extra stuff tacked on the end?

Comment: `-h` and `-k` are mutually exclusive.  Pick one.

Comment: @wfaulk Thanks, I didn't know that. I will change that in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `awk`.

```
dirsize=`du -sk /folder/path/here | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a tab. (hit most posix systems have hexdump, or the more tersely named xxd which would show you the chars printed). A more efficient solution than awk is 'cut':

```
 dirsize=`du -sk /folder/path/here | cut -f1`
```

Answer (score 0):

`du` outputs a TAB character (ASCII 9) as the delimiter.  You can verify that by piping the output to `xxd` or `od -cx`.  Therefore, you need `dirsize=${dirsize_temp/TAB*/}`.  You can type a literal TAB character at the bash prompt or in ViM by pressing `Ctrl-V` then `TAB`.

Comment: Bash inserts a TAB with `$'\t'`, so `dirsize=${dirsize_temp%%$'\t'*}` works.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for demonstrating that regex substitution syntax, you learn something new every day!  Mind if I researched it because of that and now one up it with ${var//+([[:space:]])/ } ...